# Area under the curve definition

Tags: integration, riemann-sum

I've often heard that the area under the curve is *defined* to be Riemann integral. Is it true? Or maybe we can prove that Riemann integral is equal to area under the graph of a function?

[This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=YCDvBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=riemann+integral+area+under+the+curve&source=bl&ots=yy8V27o19v&sig=tLVbIGtwg54Qs3DPCSCdUbj7EQA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAjgUahUKEwj_h-f49qvIAhVp7nIKHWVPCq4#v=onepage&q=riemann%20integral%20area%20under%20the%20curve&f=false) supports the first option. However, I think we might be able to prove that Riemann integral is equal to 'area' under the curve if we use axioms of area function.

Comment: Fundamentally this comes down to what you want area to do. And even seemingly trivial definitions can have unexpected consequences. Is curvilinear area the same "thing" as the areas of triangles and rectangles? (2400-year spoiler alert: if you're using Euclidean geometry, yes. Eudoxus proved that circles have areas proportional to the squares on their diameters.)

Answer (score 0):

You can define area in terms of measures, like Jordan measure, the value of Riemann integral on some interval equal to the Jordan measure of the area in the interval that bounded by the function and the x axis.